dap-mode java debug configuration for JUnit test
I have a gradle multiproject with different java subprojects. I'm also using lombok in my code. When I try debug a JUnit test using dap-java-debug-test-method, I therefore get error messages regarding lombok generated code, which is not available.
I have found out, that I (presumably) need to adjust vmArgs and add "-javaagent:~/workspace/java-tools/lombok.jar", but I don't know how to do this.
Can anyone provide a working debug configuration?
What I have done already:

(setq dap-java-vm-args '("-Xmx2G" "-Xms512M" "-javaagent:~/workspace/java-tools/lombok.jar")) in my .emacs with no effect


Use lsp-java-vmargs.
This is what I have in my settings.
I downgraded from lombok 1.18.34 (the latest) to 1.18.32 since I was getting an error that was causing the build to fail.
    (setq lsp-java-vmargs
          (list "-noverify"
                "-Xmx30G"
                "-XX:+UseStringDeduplication"
                "-XX:+UseParallelGC"
                "-XX:GCTimeRatio=4"
                "-XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90"
                "-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
                "-Xms1000m"
                "-XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading"
                ;; "-javaagent:/Users/marcelbecker/Downloads/lombok/lombok.jar"
                "-javaagent:/Users/marcelbecker/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.18.32/17d46b3e205515e1e8efd3ee4d57ce8018914163/lombok-1.18.32.jar"
                ))

